# neo4j csv export is not working

Tags: neo4j, export-to-csv

I am trying to export data from neo4j database in csv format. 
I used the web interfaces and got this result
[csv result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6mNFK.png)
but some fields in the column with **[n.SimplifiedText]** has large value get extra row.
I am expecting this result :
[expecting csv result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWQGV.png)

Comment: Can you please add the code you used to export this csv?

Comment: Thank you @Supamiu for helping me. I am not using any code. I just push the csv export button in neo4j web interface.[link](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/tools-webadmin.html)

Comment: Would you be willing to share the data so we can try to duplicate?

Comment: Thank you @WilliamLyon for helping me. my db size is near to 600mb but I think , you need a sample of my database in csv format am I right?

Comment: Sure, whatever you are willing to share to help debug.